# React upload problem with some file extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

When I try to upload doc or docx the extension type is appear like this `type:""`, but with pdf it works properly.

This is the custom component for form

```
let hasChanged = false;
export const renderUploadFieldForCreate = ({
    input,
    meta: { touched, error }
}) => {
    function handleOnChange (event) {
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        input.onChange(event.target.files[0]);
        hasChanged = true;
    }
    function handleOnBlur (event) {
        if (hasChanged === false) {
            event.target.value = null;
            input.onChange(null);
        }
    }
    function handleOnClick () {
        hasChanged = false;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                key={ input }
                className="form-control"
                type="file"
                onChange={ handleOnChange }
                onBlur={ handleOnBlur }
                onClick={ handleOnClick }
            />
            { touched && error && <span className="text-danger">{ error }</span> }
        </div>
    )
};
```

This is I have in the form

```
<Field name="file" component={ renderUploadFieldFor
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly which value in this code is unexpected at runtime?  It's not clear to me what you're trying to describe.

Comment: I want to upload a file type doc or Docx, and the extension is empty